# Random slide order in jssor image slider

Tags: javascript, slider, jssor

I am using a variant of jssor javascript image slider.
The code available to me is a deeply minimised code.
I am intending to make random slide order, but could not find a method.

(There is a method available for random tarnsition, but that's not what I am interested in).

I also tried a few tinkering with a few formulas around 'math' etc. in the code but to no avail. Its been weeks.

Can anyone guide?

The variant of my js is on
[Jssor Variant Slider I am using](https://cdn.rawgit.com/planthro/biblio/0ff53402/MainpageSlider.js)
Thank a lot for any advice.

Comment: You can change slide order (html code in slides container) before initialize jssor slider.

Comment: Alright, sure but how? Do you mean by a script independent of jssor? Thanks.

Comment: extract all child elements in `slides' container, and append each child element randomly.

Comment: OK perfect. I used the method given in http://jsfiddle.net/qEM8B/
and it works perfectly. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

I double checked jssor docs and it seems that there is no built in random order function. There is a very simple solution using php. Using this method you will have random slide order every time you open a website. For 10 slides there is over 3,6 million combinations so it is random.

Normally in jssor you have the following code for your slides:

```
<div data-p="375.00"><img data-u="image" data-src2="path/to/1.jpg" alt=""></div>
<div data-p="375.00"><img data-u="image" data-src2="path/to/2.jpg" alt=""></div>
<div data-p="375.00"><img data-u="image" data-src2="path/to/3.jpg" alt=""></div>
<div data-p="375.00"><img data-u="image" data-src2="path/to/4.jpg" alt=""></div>
```

---

**How to randomize slide order???**

There is a php function to generate numbers from-to `$numbers = range(1,4);`, in this case from 1 to 4.

Then, you need to shuffle your numbers. `shuffle($numbers);`

Now, all you have to do is to echo your html code.

For this method to work you **have to** use numbers as image names.

---

**WORKING EXAMPLE**

```
<?php

//enter number of slides
$number_of_slides = '4';

$numbers = range(1, $number_of_slides);
shuffle($numbers);
foreach ($numbers as $number){
    echo '<div data-p="375.00"><img data-u="image" data-src2="path/to/'.$number.'.jpg" alt=""></div>';
}
?>
```

---

If you need a random slide order for each loop you will have to find a solution using javascript.